# How to remove all but the vector function of ArduinoSTL

Tags: c++, arduino-uno

## Issue

I did a **C++** program running on an `Arduino UNO`.
I'm using `ArduinoSTL` **only** for his vector functionality, but it is using 459 bytes of the Arduino's RAM *(23% of wasted RAM is way too much for what I do)*, and it takes **5 seconds more to compile** with this library (which is annoying).

---

## What I want to do

I want to **be able to do change the size of arrays**, maybe with vectors.
I **don't want** to use libraries that **wastes RAM** for nothing.

### What I've though of doing

*I though that, maybe I could* **remove everything but the vector function(s) of `ArduinoSTL`**, so it will compile faster and take less RAM.

I attempted to do it.
In `ArduinoSTL`'s directory, there is **a lot of `.cpp` files** with one of them named `Vector.cpp`.
My solution was to erase everything except `Vector.cpp`.
It **didn't worked**.

Comment: If you're doing just rudimentary things using the vector, then you could create your own `vector` class that does just the basics.

Comment: Assuming you have the code, it should be possible to extract the required parts. Considering you came to the same conclusion but "think it won't work", I wonder why you don't just try it.

Comment: I tried to remove all but the vector files and it made a fatal error, unfortunately I'm a beginner that doesn't understand what's written in the given error :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1

#### Use regular arrays!

Using a big **regular array** can be better **sometime** because *ArduinoSTL takes a lot of memory* and removing lets enough **free space** to use such simple arrays and the compiling is way **faster**.
*In what I was doing, I didn't really needed a vector. A big array was enough.*

---

## Solution 2

#### Use stdlib.h!

It provides some functions such as `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()`.
The main advantage is that it is **standard** and is **not only for Arduino**.
Here is a piece of code in a **regular C++** coding to show how to use it.

```
#include <stdlib.h> //Mandatory for memory manipulation
#include <stdio.h>  //Used to for the command prompt

int main(){
    uint8_t* MemBlock=nullptr; //Just a pointer pointing to nothing
    int BlockSize=0;           //The size of the block in bytes

    bool Condition=true; //The condition for the if() statement
    
    if(Condition){
        BlockSize=64;
        MemBlock=(uint8_t)malloc(BlockSize); //Allocates a Memory Block

        uint8_t* P=MemBlock; //Defines a pointer that points to same location as the MemBlock pointer

        for(int i=0;i<BlockSize;i++){
            *P=i*23%101; //Change the pointed value by P
            P++; //Moves to the next value (of MemBlock)
        } 
    }else{
        BlockSize=256;
        MemBlock=(uint8_t)malloc(BlockSize); //Allocates a Memory Block

        for(int i=0;i<BlockSize;i++){
            MemBlock[i]=i*17%23; //Fills the Memory Block with values
        }
    }

    uint8_t* P=MemBlock; //Defines a pointer that points to same location as the MemBlock pointer

    for(int i=0;i<BlockSize;i++){
        std::cout<<*P++<<' '; //Displays all values of the Memory Block, *P++ is same as doing *P then P++
    }
    std::cout<<'\n'; //ends the line to show it

    free(MemBlock); //Deallocates the Memory Block to prevent "memory leaks"

    return 0;
}
```

The **Arduino IDE doesn't require to include the library as it is already included by default.**

Here is a link for more details about the library: [stdlib.h - C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/)

If anyone know a fast vector library, then feel free to share!